# Cygwin cant execute any bash command

Tags: python, bash, cygwin

I have installed cygwin in my windows 10 PC, and already installed python package on it, but when i run python command in cygwin, it says `bash: python: command not found`, i am trying run another code (cat, vm, etc) and still command not found, can someone help me?
I also try to run python on cmd but it also error, i already installed python.[image]

Comment: Provide information as image iff they can't be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Comment: How did you set the $PATH?

Answer (score 0):

You need a cygwin user ID different from your windows one,
as that is full of spaces and clearly cripping all the startup scripts;
you are in `/cygdrive/c/windows/system32` instead of your home.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-passwdinfo

This command will create a single line file, with the key info
separated by ":"

```
/bin/mkpasswd.exe -c > /etc/passwd
```

And then replace with an editor, the first field with your new name 
(for example "agus") and the sixth filed with your new HOME (for example "/home/agus"). Assuming you know hot to use VI :

```
/usr/bin/vi.exe /etc/passwd
```

After close the cygwin terminal and restart it.